# How do you load the Android bitcoin backup key onto Bitcoin Qt?

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, wallet-import, bitcoin-wallet-app

I have an Android wallet key and I want to load it onto my windows desktop. I am using Bitcoin-Qt, but i dont see an import option anywhere. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backup file produced by the Android Bitcoin app is a text file containing lines of the form

`5Jhvcnoi9LFxEcg68gTaDB3DiKEJ6TWJuMmyfjv89uEv3AbgdV 2013-01-01T12:34:56Z`

The first field is the private key.  This can be imported into bitcoin-qt using the `importprivkey` command.  Choose "Help > Debug window", go to the "Console" tab, and enter:

`importprivkey 5Jhvcnoi9LFxEcg68gTaDB3DiKEJ6TWJuMmyfjv89uEv3AbgdV`

where you paste in the private key from the file.  bitcoin-qt will be unresponsive for several minutes while it searches the blockchain for existing transactions involving the new address; this is normal.

Comment: in my case the file doesn't look this way but rather a much longer series of baseXX characters

Answer (score 0):

This guide was the only one that worked for me. My encypted backup file didn't had the mentioned format, and other guides that explained how to export the nmonic seed didn't work either with wallets like electrum or electron cash, but the exported private key as described here did:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2061691.0

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the documentation here:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_import_private_keys_v7%2B